# Iterate contents of two array and display together

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am very new to angular and was designing a possible solution using arrays. however, I could not find best possible approach to it. In other coding languages its simple to iterate and display values of 2 arrays as per index
for ex -

```
var fruit = [apple,grapes,banana];
var color = [red,green,yellow];
for (var i=0; i<fruit.length;i++)
{ 
    print('Fruit '+fruit[i]);
    print('Color ' +color[i]);
}
```

Output :

> Fruit apple
>
> Color red
>
> Fruit grapes
>
> Color green
>
> Fruit yellow

The issue-
I want to have similar functionality but am unable to do so via angular. I tried with `ng-repeat` however was not able to display as the output above. i.e iterate the items of both arrays and display. thanks

```
<div ng-repeat="f in fruit" >
    <label <b>${Fruit:}</b></label>
    <div>{{n}}</div>
    <div  ng-repeat="c in color" >
        <label <b>${color:}</b></label>
        <div>{{c}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output :

> Fruit: apple
>
> Color: red
>
> Color: green
>
> Color: yellow
>
> Fruit: grapes
>
> Color: red
>
> Color: green
>
> Color: yellow
>
> Fruit: banana
>
> Color: red
>
> Color: green
>
> Color: yellow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of two iterations, use index from first iteration i.e.

```
<div ng-repeat="f in fruit" >
    <label><b>${Fruit:}</b></label>
    <div>{{fruit[$index]}}</div>
    <label><b>${Color:}</b></label>
    <div>{{color[$index]}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: oh got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable `$index` which tracks the current offset in the looped array.

```html
<div ng-repeat="f in $ctrl.fruit" >
   <div>{{fruit[$index]}}</div>
   <div>{{color[$index]}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your example you can access the index doing `ng-repeat="(key, value) in $ctrl.fruit"` or using the `$index` prop of `ng-repeat`. [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in $ctrl.fruit">
  <label><b>Fruit: {{$ctrl.fruit[key]}}</b></label>
  <div>Color: {{$ctrl.color[key]}}</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in $ctrl.fruit">
  <label><b>Fruit: {{$ctrl.fruit[$index]}}</b></label>
  <div>Color: {{$ctrl.color[$index]}}</div>
</div>
```